# fixed point if $f'(x)\neq 1$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $ f $ is continuous and differentiable on [0,1] such that $ f '(x) \neq 1 $ for all $ x \in [0,1] $. Show that there exists a unique $ x_ {0} \in [0,1] $ such that $ f (x_ {0}) = x_ {0} $.

The problem is the existence, uniqueness and leaves the mean value theorem of derivatives and assuming that there are two fixed points.
I tried putting $ g (x) = f (x)-x $, then $ g '(x) = f' (x) -1 \neq 0$ 0 and g (x) is always increasing or always decreasing, but that does not helped me.
any idea to prove the existence. please

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need another hypothesis: The function $f(x) = 2x + 1$ has $f'(x) \neq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ but has no fixed points in this interval.

Comment: You need the extra assumption that $f([0,1])\subseteq [0,1]$. In which case continuity of $f$ is enough (apply Bolzano's theorem to $g$). Differentiability is there to give uniqueness. Otherwise $f(x)=2x+2013$ forms a counterexample

Comment: This is in reference to fixed point iteration method in which $|f'(x)|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

i think, there is something missing. Take $f(x)=(x-1)^2 +2$ clearly $f^\prime(x)=2x-2$ which is not equal to $1$ on $[0,1]$. And we have $f(x)>x$ on $[0,1]$. So $f$ is continuous and differentiable but doesnt have a fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x+\frac1x$ is counter example. You can change problem hypothesis as $\forall x\in\mathbb{R} : f'(x)<L$ for some fixed $L<1$ and then construct and discuss on this sequence : $(f^{(n)}(x_0))$ which $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ is $n$ times combination of $f$.